# Invalid API Key - Accessing OSHA data

Tags: usa, data.gov, api, labor

I am trying got download OSHA data via API. I have registered my email and got key.
When i sent request its throwing invalid API KEY.

```
https://data.dol.gov/get/accident?KEY=REMOVED
```

What should we give for "Application Name" when creating Tokens ?

```
https://data.dol.gov/get/violation_gen_duty_std?KEY=REMOVED
```

I gave 'violation_gen_duty_std" for the above one.

Any help appreciated .
API Details are found at http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/#osha_inspection

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you got it right in [your answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6111/3680). The "data.dol.gov" URLs use the newer Department of Labor API (v2), which sends the Key in the http headers.

See the data.dol.gov tab for more information at:

http://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide/

As far as the application name goes when creating a Key/token, you can use whatever you would like -- generally it is the name of your software application, project, product, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource; 

   WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://data.dol.gov/get/inspection/limit/0");
    webResource.header("X-API-KEY", "REMOVED");
```